# Por que não preciso passar parâmetros para essa função?

Tags: javascript, eventos, funções

Gostaria de saber como funciona a passagem de função como parâmetro em JS, estou iniciando na linguagem agora e precisei fazer uma chamada de `EventListenner`

`document.getElementsByClassName("informacao")[0].addEventListener("mouseover", troca(banner2));`

Gostaria de saber também porque ele não aceita `troca(banner2)` na declaração com os parâmetros de minha função, porém aceita se eu passar somente o nome da função ou se declarar como função anônima (`function(){}`).
Obrigado!

Comment: É só um exemplo para aprender a funcionalidade mesmo kkk

Answer (score 4):

O solução seria assim:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("informacao")[0].addEventListener("mouseover",
 function() { troca(banner2) });
```

`troca(banner2)` é uma chamada de função. `addEventListener` não espera uma chamada de função e sim uma uma função. Esse `function() { }` que eu coloquei em volta do seu código cria uma função que, por sua vez, fará a chamada que você quer no momento que o evento ocorrer.

Talvez ajude pensar que o corpo de `troca` poderia vir dentro dessa função anônima (assim, não seria uma função dentro da outra). Desse jeito, há simplesmente uma indireção (e uma passagem de parâmetros)

Comment: Obrigado :)
Então o function eu consigo fazer com que ele "entenda" que é uma função e não uma chamada? Não seria de certa forma uma gambiarra?

Comment: Pode-se pensar que sim, mas isso é questão ideológica. Algumas linguagens separam o conceito de função do conceito de função anônima. Mas há quem prefira a simplicidade do Javascript. É fato que, comparado à verbosidade do Java pré-8, por exemplo, você provavelmente vai preferir esse jeito aqui. :)

Comment: Se você parar pra pensar, a gambiarra seria se o '`ddEventListener("mouseover", troca(banner2))` funcionasse. Em qualquer outra função do Javascript se você fizer `foo(troca(banner2))`o que o código faz é avaliar o `troca(banner2)` e passar o valor pra `foo`. Para que funcionasse da forma da sua pergunta, os eventlisteners teriam que ser tratados de forma especial pela linguagem.

Comment: Isso mesmo, Hugo. É o caso do Java, por exemplo. Lá tem uma interface pra cada Listener. Mesmo com o 8, temos funções Lambda que não são a mesma coisa que os métodos. Python tem lambdas, mas são limitados a expressões. Javascript segue essa filosofia de ser o mais genérico possível. Isso pode ser visto como algo bom ou ruim.

Comment: Certo, desculpe mas estou um pouco confuso ainda:/ Resumindo, em passagem de funcao por parametro, SEMPRE ou eu passo uma função anônima ou eu passo apenas o nome da função(sem uso de parenteses)? Na hora da criação de uma função que irá receber uma função em seu parâmetro eu trato como se fosse uma variável(sem o uso de parenteses) ? Caso for isso mesmo é bem mais simples que eu pensei :) Mas tem uma explicação, um por que disso?

Comment: Não necessariamente. Você pode passar um nome de uma função definida previamente sem os parêntesis. A questão da função anônima aqui é que sua função exige parâmetros e o addEventListener não possui um parâmetro que seja um argumento para a função passada. Algumas outras funções que recebem funções possuem essa facilidade. Se a função que você quer chamar não exige parâmetros, basta passar o nome dela.

Comment: O que importa é passar uma expressão cujo valor é uma função.  Dá para experimentar com isso indo no console, escrevendo uma expressão e apertando enter. escrevendo `1+1` ele vai imprimir `2` no console. escrevendo `alert` ele vai imprimir `function alert()` no console. `alert()` ele vai mostrar um popup e depois imprimir `undefined` no console (que foi o valor retornado pela chamada ao alert)

Answer (score 3):

Em Javascript o valor da expressão `troca(banner2)` é o valor de retorno de `troca`. Quando você chama

```
blah.addEventListener("mouseover", troca(banner2));
```

é como se você tivesse escrito

```
var tmp = troca(banner2);
blah.addEventListener("mouseover", tmp);
```

Como addEventListener espera receber uma função como parâmetro você deve ou passar a função direto (pelo nome, sem parênteses), ou passar uma função anônima ou alguma outra expressão cujo valor no final seja uma função.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa a se considerar é que em JavaScript funções são objetos de primeira classe, o que significa que podem ser atribuídas à variáveis e passadas como argumento para outras funções da mesma forma como você faria com uma string ou um número ou um array ou etc...

Sendo assim, é perfeitamente natural fazer algo como isso:

```
var minhaFuncao = function( mensagem ) {
    console.log( mensagem );
};

// ou...

var minhaOutraFuncao = funcaoQueFazAlgumaCoisa;

function funcaoQueFazAlgumaCoisa( mensagem ) { console.log( mensagem ); }
```

E depois isso:

```
minhaFuncao( "Chamando minhaFunção!" );

// ou...

minhaOutraFuncao( "Chamando minhaOutraFuncao" );

// ou...

funcaoQueFazAlgumaCoisa( "Chamando funcaoQueFazAlgumaCoisa" );
```

Com isso em mente, considere a seguinte função:

```
function passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer( mensagem, umaFuncaoQualquer ) {
    umaFuncaoQualquer( mensagem );
}
```

A função acima espera receber como primeiro argumento uma string e como segundo uma função, então poderíamos invocá-la da seguinte forma:

```
passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer( "Olá, Mundo!!!", function( msg ) { console.log( msg ) } );

// ou...

function umaFuncaoQualquer( msg ) {
    console.log( msg );
}

passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer( "Olá, Mundo!!!", umaFuncaoQualquer );
```

E seu eu fizer isso:

```
passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer( "Olá", "Mundo" );
```

Vai gerar um erro, pois seria a mesma coisa que fazer:

```
"Mundo"();
```

E não se pode invocar uma string, não é mesmo?

Agora, se eu fizer da forma como você demonstrou:

```
passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer( "Olá, Mundo!!!", umaFuncaoQualquer() );
```

O que acontece é que eu invocando `umaFuncaoQualquer` e passando o valor retornado por ela (seja ele qual for) como segundo argumento de `passeMeUmaFuncaoQualquer`, o que gera um erro.